# Print task with client-side graphics and dynamic classbreakrenderer not working

Tags: javascript, printing, arcgis, esri

I'm using the ArcGIS Javascript API 3.6 with ArcGIS Server 10.2 and want to export the map with client-side graphics.

When no graphics are present, the printtask works fine.

But as soon as i have created graphics, by creating a QueryTask which return geometries, then querying a different webserver for statistics, which are then added as attributes to the graphics, then a classbreakrenderer is added based on the min/max values for the statistics.

The following error is returned:

```
{"error":{"code":400,"message":"Unable to complete operation.","details":["Error executing tool.: Layer \"map_graphics\": Field 'AantalKlachten' not part of schema for this feature collection.\nFailed to execute (Export Web Map).\nFailed to execute (Export Web Map Task)."]}}
```

Already added field 'AantalKlachten' to the features (which was not there before).

The JSON POST is

```
Format=PNG32
Layout_Template=MAP_ONLY
Web_Map_as_JSON={"mapOptions":{"showAttribution":true,"extent":{"xmin":-76386.71831343666,"ymin":267241.1031242062,"xmax":391926.71831343666,"ymax":664116.8968757938,"spatialReference":{"wkid":28992}},"spatialReference":{"wkid":28992},"scale":2500000},"operationalLayers":[{"id":"layer0","title":"layer0","opacity":1,"minScale":2500000,"maxScale":2268,"url":"http://qaj4041/arcgis/rest/services/Nederland/Nederland/MapServer"},{"id":"layer1","title":"layer1","opacity":0.7,"minScale":0,"maxScale":0,"url":"http://qaj4041/arcgis/rest/services/Nederland/Operationeel/MapServer","visibleLayers":[0],"layers":[]},{"id":"map_graphics","minScale":0,"maxScale":0,"featureCollection":{"layers":[{"layerDefinition":{"name":"polygonLayer","geometryType":"esriGeometryPolygon","drawingInfo":{"renderer":{"type":"classBreaks","field":"AantalKlachten","defaultSymbol":{"color":[0,0,0,64],"outline":{"color":[0,0,0,255],"width":1,"type":"esriSLS","style":"esriSLSSolid"},"type":"esriSFS","style":"esriSFSSolid"},"minValue":2,"classBreakInfos":[{"symbol":{"color":[0,140,0,128],"outline":{"color":[0,0,0,255],"width":0.75,"type":"esriSLS","style":"esriSLSSolid"},"type":"esriSFS","style":"esriSFSSolid"},"classMaxValue":3},{"symbol":{"color":[0,255,0,128],"outline":{"color":[0,0,0,255],"width":0.75,"type":"esriSLS","style":"esriSLSSolid"},"type":"esriSFS","style":"esriSFSSolid"},"classMaxValue":4},{"symbol":{"color":[255,255,0,128],"outline":{"color":[0,0,0,255],"width":0.75,"type":"esriSLS","style":"esriSLSSolid"},"type":"esriSFS","style":"esriSFSSolid"},"classMaxValue":5},{"symbol":{"color":[255,140,0,128],"outline":{"color":[0,0,0,255],"width":0.75,"type":"esriSLS","style":"esriSLSSolid"},"type":"esriSFS","style":"esriSFSSolid"},"classMaxValue":6},{"symbol":{"color":[255,0,0,128],"outline":{"color":[0,0,0,255],"width":0.75,"type":"esriSLS","style":"esriSLSSolid"},"type":"esriSFS","style":"esriSFSSolid"},"classMaxValue":7}]}}},"featureSet":{"geometryType":"esriGeometryPolygon","features":[{"geometry":{"rings":[[[109569,409744],[112648,409574],[112675,409579],[112741,409571],[115651,404880],[117057,403521],[117057,403521],[117070,403508],[117288,403264],[117965,402312],[117966,402304],[117947,401594],[118542,400812],[120099,401875],[120336,402109],[120371,402230],[120369,402237],[120359,402267],[120343,402312],[120338,402328],[120328,402358],[120325,402369],[120323,402371],[120322,402375],[120321,402379],[120318,402386],[120316,402392],[120313,402401],[120312,402405],[120309,402413],[120360,402440],[120423,402473],[120414,402493],[120406,402512],[120524,402490],[120653,402357],[120655,402355],[120658,402358],[120715,402465],[120755,402597],[120722,402626],[120694,402651],[120681,402663],[120753,402729],[120784,402756],[120761,402796],[120748,402821],[120724,402865],[120700,402907],[120695,402917],[120691,402924],[120688,402931],[120687,402934],[120683,402943],[120676,402958],[120658,402998],[120655,403006],[120648,403020],[120622,403078],[120594,403134],[120541,403235],[120501,403310],[120497,403317],[120557,403386],[120566,403397],[120582,403413],[120619,403447],[121017,403757],[122125,403826],[122319,403755],[121779,400857],[119137,398098],[117923,395273],[121870,391415],[121946,391338],[121940,391277],[121920,391084],[121881,390726],[121794,389917],[121768,389678],[121758,389593],[121756,389577],[121080,388570],[120436,387783],[119978,387705],[117119,388107],[115112,389746],[112905,390734],[112861,390750],[112827,390761],[112809,390766],[112410,390857],[112349,390839],[112234,390804],[111934,390710],[111861,390688],[111812,390672],[111448,390558],[110943,390279],[107441,386395],[104991,383352],[102610,382044],[95755,381891],[95558,383477],[95518,383836],[95407,384843],[96707,387475],[98519,389141],[103018,395085],[102865,395141],[102757,395190],[102601,395264],[100992,396413],[100970,396432],[100242,397069],[100106,398076],[100224,400452],[100576,404335],[100830,404547],[100929,404608],[101026,404649],[101038,404654],[104342,405302],[104383,405310],[104432,405319],[104529,405334],[104590,405343],[104636,405347],[104683,405351],[104740,405351],[104789,405348],[104845,405341],[104873,405336],[104903,405330],[104905,405330],[104916,405327],[104941,405320],[104975,405311],[104997,405304],[105052,405283],[105100,405264],[105214,405215],[105301,405177],[105364,405151],[105410,405133],[105451,405120],[105502,405106],[105549,405096],[105593,405089],[105650,405083],[105707,405079],[105762,405080],[105819,405083],[105873,405089],[105935,405099],[105989,405110],[106022,405120],[106089,405140],[106147,405164],[107226,405696],[108632,408161],[108565,408517],[108444,409095],[109569,409744]]],"spatialReference":{"wkid":28992,"latestWkid":28992}},"attributes":{"POSTCODE":"48","AantalKlachten":2,"AantalKlagers":1}}]}}]}}],"exportOptions":{"outputSize":[800,1100],"dpi":96}}
 f=json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove "field": "AantalKlachten" and specify fields in the layerDefinition section.  Try adding this to the layerDefinition:

```
"fields":[
 {
   "name":"POSTCODE",
   "type":"esriFieldTypeString"
 },
 {
   "name":"AantalKlachten",
   "type":"esriFieldTypeInteger"
 },
 {
   "name":"AantalKlagers",
   "type":"esriFieldTypeInteger"
 }
]
```